# [Structured Streaming]: Structured Streaming into Redshift sink

Tags: apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift, spark-structured-streaming

Is it possible to write the Dataframe backed by Kafka Streaming source into AWS Redshift, we have in the past used [spark-redshift](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift) to write into Redshift, but I presume it will not work with `DataFrame##writeStream`. Also writing with JDBC connector with `ForeachWriter` is also may not be a good idea given the way Redshift works.

One possible approach that I have come across from [Yelp blog](https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2016/10/redshift-connector.html) is to write the files into S3 and then invoke [Redshift `COPY`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) with a Manifest file having the S3 Object path, in case of Structured Streaming, how can I control the files into which I write to S3? and also have a separate trigger to create a manifest file after writing say 5 files into S3.

Any other possible solution is also appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to use spark-redshift in structured streaming but you have to implement a few additional classes in your own fork. First of all you need a RedshiftSink that should implement `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.Sink` interface:

```scala
private[redshift] class RedshiftSink(
    sqlContext: SQLContext,
    parameters: MergedParameters,
    redshiftWriter: RedshiftWriter) extends Sink {

  private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)

  @volatile private var latestBatchId = -1L

  override def toString(): String = "RedshiftSink"

  override def addBatch(batchId: Long, data: DataFrame): Unit = {
    if (batchId <= latestBatchId) {
      log.info(s"Skipping already committed batch $batchId")
    } else {
      val mode = if (parameters.overwrite) SaveMode.Overwrite else SaveMode.Append
      redshiftWriter.saveToRedshift(sqlContext, data, mode, parameters)
      latestBatchId = batchId
    }
  }
}
```

Then `com.databricks.spark.redshift.DefaultSource` should be extended with implementation of `org.apache.spark.sql.sources.StreamSinkProvider`:

```scala
  /**
   * Creates a Sink instance
   */
  override def createSink(
    sqlContext: SQLContext,
    parameters: Map[String, String],
    partitionColumns: Seq[String],
    outputMode: OutputMode): Sink = {
      new RedshiftSink(sqlContext, Parameters.mergeParameters(parameters), new RedshiftWriter(jdbcWrapper, s3ClientFactory))
  }
```

Now you should be able to use it in structured streaming:

```scala
dataset.writeStream()
        .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
        .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
        .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
        .queryName("redshift-stream")
        .start()
```

#### Update

To fix issue with reporting metrics to StreamExecution `RedshiftWriter.unloadData()` has to be changed to use `data.queryExecution.toRdd.mapPartitions` instead of `data.rdd.mapPartitions` since `data.rdd` creates a new plan that is not visible to StreamExecution (which uses the existing plan to collect metrics). It also requires changing a conversion functions to this:

```scala
val conversionFunctions: Array[(InternalRow, Int) => Any] = data.schema.fields.map { field =>
  field.dataType match {
    case DateType =>
      val dateFormat = Conversions.createRedshiftDateFormat()
      (row: InternalRow, ordinal: Int) => {
        if (row.isNullAt(ordinal)) null else dateFormat.format(
          DateTimeUtils.toJavaDate(row.getInt(ordinal)))
      }
    case TimestampType =>
      val timestampFormat = Conversions.createRedshiftTimestampFormat()
      (row: InternalRow, ordinal: Int) => {
        if (row.isNullAt(ordinal)) null else timestampFormat.format(
          DateTimeUtils.toJavaTimestamp(row.getLong(ordinal)))
      }
    case StringType =>
      (row: InternalRow, ordinal: Int) => {
        if (row.isNullAt(ordinal)) null else row.getString(ordinal)
      }
    case dt: DataType =>
      (row: InternalRow, ordinal: Int) => {
        if (row.isNullAt(ordinal)) null else row.get(ordinal, dt)
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked!! ALMOST!! They use Dataset.rdd() function in RedshiftWriter which ended up with org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()

Comment: Yes sure, I forgot to add writeStream.start(). See updated answer

Comment: Im sorry for not being clear, Dataframe.rdd that is done in RedshiftWriter checks if the Dataframe is streaming in UnsupportedOpertionChecker class of Spark SQL api and raises that exception. So we cannot directly use RedshiftWriter in this case, and it has a lot of private methods so cannot extend that too. So may have to go for a parallel implementation of it

Comment: RedshiftWriter uses data.rdd that creates a new plan so that StreamExecution doesn't know about it (leads to missing metrics, watermark updates). But whenever stream is started it shouldn't throw an exception. Which spark version do you use? And how do you construct your stream?

Answer (score 0):

Spark is able to load normal dataframes to Redshift very effectively but I haven't worked with streams in Spark yet.

If you can continuously write the stream output to a standard df then, at a specified interval, you could load that df to Redshift and empty it.

The other alternative would be sending the stream to Kinesis and using Kinesis Firehose to load it to Redshift. Seems excessive to add another streaming layer to the stack though.